# What's the difference between stack's children declaration in Flutter

Tags: animation, flutter, dart, stack, widget

I have written List and [items] in my code. When using  [items] the animation works properly but in case of  List it doesn't work at all. What's the difference between the two declarations?

P.S. I'm a total newbie in flutter. Hope to get some help.

```dart
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<Widget> cards = [];
  AnimationController _controller;
  double _point = 2.3;

  Widget _initCard(int index) {
    Animation _animLeft = Tween(begin: _point * index, end: _point * 8 * index)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.linear))
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {});
          });

    return Container(
      width: 50.0,
      height: 50.0,
      color: Colors.red
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: _animLeft.value.toDouble(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 3));
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
      cards.add(_initCard(i));
    }
    _controller.forward();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            width: 320,
            height: 520,
            color: Colors.deepOrange,
            child: Stack(
              overflow: Overflow.visible,
              children: cards,
      //         children: <Widget>[
      //           _initCard(0),
      //           _initCard(1),
      // ],
    )));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code with us so we can see what you tried doing?

Comment: @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            width: 320,
            height: 520,
            color: Colors.deepOrange,
            child: Stack(
                overflow: Overflow.visible,
                //children: cards,
                children: <Widget>[
                    _initCard(0),
                    _initCard(1),
                    _initCard(2),
                    _initCard(3),
                    _initCard(4),
                ],
            )));
    }

Comment: P.S_2. I'm very sorry to past the code just like this but I couldn't figure out how to change the syntax.

Comment: @seda you should paste it into the body of the question.

Comment: @alexpfx  I did so, but it showed syntax errors which wasn't possible to fix as I followed flutter's syntax

Comment: @Seda No, you should *edit* your question to include your code in your question.  It is not syntax-checked; there's no reason why you wouldn't be able to paste your code.  I've gone ahead and done it for you.

Comment: @Seda In your code, what is `cards`?  What is it set to?  Please provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks, I edited the code with `children:cards` which is not working. Cards is a list of widgets (Container) here.

Answer (score 0):

Stack is used to arrange children in relatively. If you want to display list of some data use Listview or Listview.Builder().

Or

If you want to used Stack only, you can display data using Position and Center widgets

Comment: I didn't need Listview.Builder(). I've used Positioned Widget and its left argument just like this left:animation.value. The animation.value changes repeatedly during its performance but the widget doesn't move. This happens in case of writing children:cards, where cards is type of List<Widget>.

Comment: Okay, I think problem is you are using two children in stack. I have search about overflow. some times it do not work. if you want to display two list types something.. you can use Column inside stack's children.

Comment: Thanks. We need to display the widgets one on the top of the other (like Stack) and not one after another.

Comment: Here you can see screenshots of code.
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/NznrH.png]
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhpB0.png]

Comment: If i am not wrong. i think you should write cards[0], cards[1],.. and so on instead of initCards[0]. because you already add initCards widget in Cards list. now you have to called that list elements as a stack children.

Comment: I'v tried the way you told me, but there's no difference. Animations work but the widgets don't move. I don't get what's the difference of creating everything in advance or calling a function to create a widget

Comment: I do not have experience with animation. if Widget shows then something wrong with Animation. You have to check that animation code. May your _animLeft animation not attached properly with Container left property.